# vim + tmux configuration

Tags: vim, tmux

I am using tmux and vim together. I like to have tabs within vim and I have mapped `<C-Left>` to go to left tab in vim. When I use this vim within tmux, this doesn't work and I get some error like `No definition found`. I am using default configs for tmux i.e no change in `.tmux.conf` file How should I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/401926/how-to-get-shiftarrows-and-ctrlarrows-working-in-vim-in-tmux)?

Comment: The answer forces me to use ijkl to navigate within file. I want arrow keys to be used for that and <C-Right> to shift between tabs.

Comment: The accepted answer allows you to do `nmap <C-Right> :tabNext<CR>`. It works perfectly, here. Also you didn't talk about `hjkl` vs arrows in your question. Add a pragraph or ask another question.